# Set title of Terminator terminal tab in config

Tags: terminator

I am trying to setup a terminator terminal with a few tabs.
I would like to change the title of the tabs in the config
so when I launch the terminal tabs, they are properly titled/named.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In `~/.config/terminator/config`, specify `labels` for the parent node of the tabs.

For example, I have a two-tab default layout:

```
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child0]]]
      order = 0
      parent = ""
      position = 0:-20
      size = 1920, 478
      type = Window
    [[[child1]]]
      labels = Root, None
      order = 0
      parent = child0
      type = Notebook
    [[[terminal1]]]
      order = 0
      parent = child1
      profile = root
      type = Terminal
    [[[terminal2]]]
      order = 1
      parent = child1
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
```

`child1` contains the actual tabs (of type `Terminal`), so I specify `labels` in it:

```
labels = Root, None
```

The first tab gets a fixed title of `Root` and the second tab's title is left alone (so my shell, and any other commands I run, can set it).

Comment: AWESOME !!! thank you muru .. this is exactly what i wanted to do .[ SOLVED ]

Answer (score 0):

Not exacltly the same, but I was struggling to name my terminal windows.

To do that you can simply add `title = "whatever"` to the desired terminal like this:

```
...
[[[terminal2]]]
      title = "whatever"
      order = 1
      parent = child1
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
...
```

It took me a while to figure this out, because aparantly you need to completely **stop all terminator processes** before changes to the config file take any effect (which does make sense in retrospect).